# Do not run all test on build

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I have a Qt/QML project using CMake, which contains a sub-directory for the tests.

But every-time I build the project on QtCreator (ctrl+b, or "build project "), every test have is run. My problem is that some of them are linked to graphic event and thus show a windows that will flash on the screen. I would like to run these tests only when I explicitly want.

Is there a way to build without specific tests?

Edit:
Top CmakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Projet LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Quick Quick3D REQUIRED)

set(MAIN_FILE src/main.cpp)

set(SOURCE_FILES
[...]
    )

set(HEADER_FILES
[...]
    )

set(QRC_FILES
[...]
    )

# Compile everything except main.cpp in a separate library (needed for unit testing)
set(LIB_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_LIB)
add_library(${LIB_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${QRC_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${LIB_NAME} Qt6::Core Qt6::Quick Qt6::Quick3D)
target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/)

# Link the library to the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAIN_FILE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIB_NAME})

add_subdirectory(test)
```

The main folder contains a subfolder test, containing the Test CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Projet_Test)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES
[...]
)

set(HEADER_FILES
[...])

set(QML_TESTCASES
[...]
)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Quick Qml QuickTest REQUIRED)

set(QML_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_IMPORT_PATH};${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}" CACHE INTERNAL "Standard Qt variable")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${QML_TESTCASES})

# Qt macro where all qml testcase are located
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -DQUICK_TEST_SOURCE_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
add_definitions(-DQML_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE  Qt6::Core Qt6::Quick Qt6::Quick3D Qt6::QuickTest PRIVATE Projet_LIB)

add_test(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME} COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the build settings on the projects tab? Maybe share the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: No I did not, so the build step indicates `cmake --build . --target all`. Added CMakeList on the post

Comment: You probably have "automatically run" set to "all"/"selected" in the section "Testing" of the options?

Comment: That's it: I changed to selected and don't run the graphics test everytime